# Jackson 2 @JsonConstructor with partial json deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

Given:

- The following bean:

  ```
  public class A {
     private final int a;
     private final int b;

     public A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
     }
  }
  ```
- The following json:

  ```
  {"a":1}
  ```
- A parameter outside of json:

  ```
  int b = 2;
  ```

I'd like to deserialize this to the equivalent of:

```
A a = new A(1, 2);
```

I know I can:

- Make the bean mutable, deserialize `a` from json, and set `b` afterwards
- Deserialize json into another bean (`A2`) that only has what json has (`a` in this case), then create an instance of `A` from it and `b`

Is there a (succinct) way to do this without resorting to any of the above?

Comment: Jackson support custom deserializers, you can create one for Class A.

Comment: @ThePerson That wouldn't be more succinct than the above. Also, how would the parameter (`b` above) be passed in into the deserializer?

Comment: Where do you want the value of `b` to come from? When you create a deserializer, you can pass arguments into it before registering it with Jackson. You can pass into this a supplier, or a single value, whatever works for your use-case. If it's only known to an object that is using `A`, then all you can do is call a setter.

Comment: If it's more succint or not depends on how you use it. If you are deserializing this in many places, then you've just put this code in one place and it'll work everywhere, rather than spreading `A.setB()` around the codebase. Only a suggestion anyway, I'd be interested in knowing how you intend to use this.

Comment: @ThePerson `b` comes from outside of json. Example: say `A(a, b)` is a `Person(name, age)` whose `name` is in json, but `age` is in a DB table located via that `name`. So: 1) read `name` from json 2) read `age` from DB using that `name` as the parameter 3) construct `Person(name, age)`. I know I can do that in two steps, but that means either 1) a non-immutable `Person(name, age)` or 2) another `TemporaryPerson(name)` bean that then gets transformed into `Person(name, age)`. Hope that clarifies.